# Camera Intent call onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

In my app I want to click photo from camera and want to get content `URI` from camera result in `onActivityResult()` method.

In my App I am getting content URL using below method.

```
Uri currImageURI;
ArrayList<Uri> imageItems = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if((requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) || (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_FROM_LIB && resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
                currImageURI = data.getData();
                imageItems.add(currImageURI);
                Toast.makeText(UpdateMyServiceActivity.this, "Image added.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

I added uri in `ArrayList` (Because user can upload multiple images).

There is save button in my app.

When user click on save button, I pass `imageItems` to `AsyncTask` for upload image to server.

**But here is problem.**

When user click on save button, I am getting **imageItems null**.

I debug my app.
After add URI to ArrayList, below `Activity` methods are called.

```
onResume()
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

That's why I am getting arrayList null.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
currImageURI = data.getData();
```

If you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, this is incorrect code. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`, though a small number of camera apps will. Instead, you supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` itself. Then, you hold onto whatever value you used with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and you look there for your image in `onActivityResult()`.

> That's why I am getting arrayList null.

Your activity is being destroyed and recreated, probably because your process was terminated while the camera app was in the foreground. This is perfectly normal. Your process can be terminated any time your app is not in the foreground.

> How to solve this issue?

Hold onto the `ArrayList` via the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: Every Time I m getting URI from camera intent. Example URI : `content://media/external/images/media/8484`

Comment: @ChiragSavsani: You will not get one from any Nexus device. And if you read the documentation, `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not documented to return a `Uri`. There is no requirement for a camera app to return a `Uri`.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot for pointing for this topic. So now I have to change my code. Thanks a lot for information.